# using jquery for modal asp.net ajax udate progress

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updateprogress

I have asp.net UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress controls on my form . I'm trying to make Update progress modal by [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos) or jquery itself .

the `$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);` doesn't work , Because I'm using UpdatePanel and Server-Side ASP.NET ajax .

I've noticed in Partial postback just UpdateProgress disply style change from `display: none` to `display: block`

So I'm wondering if there is any style changing event in jquery to call `$.blockUI();` or any other solution in order to use [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos) with asp.net updatepanel and UpdateProgress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this script below the ScriptManager control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);
    prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

    var blockTimeout = null;

    function initializeRequest(sender, args) {
        blockTimeout = window.setTimeout($.blockUI, 500);
    }

    function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
        clearTimeout(blockTimeout);
        $.unblockUI();
    }
</script>
```

Timeout allows to avoid blocking page for very short async requests.

Comment: @Yriy:Is there any way i could call $.unblockUI() method on Error ?

Comment: @Mostafa, yes, you may use PageRequestManager's endRequest event handler to call unblockUI method instead of the pageLoad function